# Javascript Facebook Login Flow PWA

Tags: javascript, facebook, ember.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm using EmberJS to build a PWA that implements Facebook Login.
When it's used as a "installed" PWA Facebook SDK is not working and gives a blank page after permissions are given. So I had to implement Facebook Login Flow and everything was working until lst week.

```
var permissionUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=CLIENTID&redirect_uri="+window.location.href+"&scope=email,public_profile";
window.location = permissionUrl;
```

This code only runs after checking if it's in "Standalone".
Now when I run the same thing in my Android phone it opens Facebook App, asks for permission and goes to de redirect but in a webview inside Facebook App.

The code was not changed from when it was working.

Any help would be much appreciated.